# WebView Gets reload after clicking on TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview, flutter-dependencies, flutterwebviewplugin

i am currently working on a flutter app that is working on SDK 2.10.4. I have implemented a webView which includes some form Fields in a web page. When i click on a TextFormField, my WebView gets reloaded. And this process is repeatable.
and says that `WebView.destroy() called while WebView is still attached to window.`
Tried many solutions, like changing the WebView Packages, Upgrading SDK, but nothing solved my issue.
When i Updated my project's SDK Version to 2.18.0, it gave errors of Null Safety in Every File i have created in the entire project.
So is there any solution? that i don't have to upgrade my sdk and my webview will work fine ?

This is my Flutter Doctor console.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Hey, can you show us some code snippets? You may do something on a onTap event

Comment: The TextFormField is inside of WebPage, when i click on that TextField, then my webview gets realoaded.